# matlab - get vectors from a matrix (quiverplot)

Tags: matlab

I am reading in an image and storing it into a 2d matrix. after doing some computation on it as shown here:

```
im = rgb2gray(imread('ellipse.png'));
im = im(:,:,1);
w = size(im,1);                   
h = size(im,2);                               
[dx,dy] = gradient(double(im));                
[x y] = meshgrid(1:h,1:w);                    
a = zeros(temp);
lambda = 1;
Ox =-1.^lambda.* -x;
Oy =-1.^lambda.* y;
hold on                                   
quiver(x,y,Ox,Oy)
```

I get the following image from the quiverplot:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0iDswLYaZ0zR2lUQ2NkZnd1QXM/edit?pli=1

My question is, how do I access those vectors (arrows) from the quiverplot? I need to use those vectors in a cross product later on. Thanks.

Comment: `Ox` and `Oy` in your code *are* those vectors (x and y components, respectively).  `quiver` isn't calculating them, it is just plotting them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. if i try doing cross(Ox,Oy) then I get an error, because cross expects vectors, but here I am supplying matrices. so how do i retrieve the vectors from Ox and Oy so that they are suitable for using in a cross product?

Comment: also, if i do cross(Ox(1,1),Oy(1,1) I get the following error:

??? Error using ==> cross at 37
A and B must have at least one dimension of length 3.

Comment: A 2-D vector would be `[Ox(1,1) Oy(1,1)]`.  You have to figure out where your third dimension is coming from, whether you're going to make it constant (0, if you want the z-component to be in the xy-plane) or what.  Also, I suspect there's something wrong with the code snippet above.  You are calculating `dx` and `dy` but then not using them...

Comment: @brucezepplin: could you please use an image hosting service like `imgur.com` instead of Google drive (its asking me to request permission for access)

Comment: Yes I see now, I'm happy to append z as well as the result will be in x-y plane. THanks very much! also I will be using dx and dy just haven't got round to it yet.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be stack your matrices into a big NxMx3 block and call cross against it like this:

```
myVectors = cat(3, Ox, Oy, zeros(size(Ox)));
someOtherVectors = myVectors+1;
result = cross(myVectors,someOtherVectors );
```

Another would be to write your own cross function like this:

```
function result = cross2d(Ax, Ay, Bx, By)
      result = Ax.*By - Ay.*Bx;
end
```

And call it like this in your code:

```
Mx = Ox + 1;
My = Oy + 1;

result2 = cross2d(Ox, Oy, Mx, My)
```

(Note that I just made up a new set of vectors to take the cross product against by adding one... you would use your own)